# Why do numeric hyperlinks make an entire cell clickable and the text uneditable?

Tags: excel

I have notice that if you insert a hyperlink into any cell in Excel and set the text to display to be a number (1, for example), it causes the entire cell to now be clickable in addition to preventing you from changing the hyperlink text afterwards. If you try to change the hyperlink text by going to `Edit Hyperlink` the `Text to Display` is always `Selection in Document`.

If you do the exact same thing but make the `Text to Display` an alpha character (like `a`), it works just fine and you can edit the hyperlink `Text to Display` without issue.

This is causing problems because I am trying to read Excel data using Interop libraries and even those libraries are unable to read the `Text to Display` when it is set as a whole number with no decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a Hyperlink like:

[image]

You can later edit the "Friendly Name" by selecting the cell and doing the edit in the Formula Bar.